# Include increments by 1 in the x axis of the histogram/boxplot drawn using Python

Tags: python, histogram, boxplot

I am trying to draw a boxplot in Python with the `variableAmount` represented the x axis and the `Frequency` represented in the y axis as shown in the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Frequency = [15097,1207,645,93,68,15,19,10,20,3,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
variableAmount = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
'10', '12','13','14', '15', '20', '23', '24', '26', '30'] #sample names

plt.bar(variableAmount, Frequency)
plt.set_xticks(1)
plt.set_yticks(1)

plt.xticks(variableAmount)
plt.yticks(Frequency) #This may be included or excluded as per need
plt.xlabel('Variables per method')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

I am having the following plot as an output and the problem that I have is that I would like to have a tick at every increment of 1 in the x axis. As you can see in the graph below, 9 and 11 are both missing from the x axis and I would like every integer value to be included from 0 up to 30 in the x axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first problem is than variable amount is a list of string.
And I think you need to define the complete list of ticks for x you want to make appear.

You can solve it with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Frequency = [15097,1207,645,93,68,15,19,10,20,3,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
variableAmount = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
'10', '12','13','14', '15', '20', '23', '24', '26', '30'] #sample names


variableAmount_int=[int(x) for x in variableAmount]
X_ticks_array=[i for i in range(min(variableAmount_int),max(variableAmount_int)+1)]

plt.bar(variableAmount_int, Frequency)
plt.xticks(X_ticks_array)
plt.xlabel('Variables per method')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I thing it is not posible to do this directly in your plot. But you can create new variable to store an new version of your list

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Frequency = [15097,1207,645,93,68,15,19,10,20,3,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
variableAmount = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 23, 24, 26, 30] #sample names
New_Frequency = []

for i in range(31):
    if i in variableAmount:
        New_Frequency.append(Frequency[variableAmount.index(i)])
    else:
        New_Frequency.append(0)

variableAmount = [i for i in range(31)]
plt.bar(variableAmount, New_Frequency)

plt.xlabel('Variables per method')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

Comment: variableAmount = [i for i in range(31)]?? still not working

Comment: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_xticks'

Comment: still not working `variableAmount = [i for in range(31)]` invalid syntax thrown by the compiler